# Simple integral question for expression of constant term

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$\frac{dy}{dx}\ = \frac{-1}{x^3}\\$

is the solution:

$y = \frac{1}{2x^2} + k$

or

$y = \frac{1}{2x^2} - k$

Comment: $k$ is an *arbitrary* constant. If you wanted to signify an addition of $+5$, then you could choose $k=5$ in the first form, but you could also choose $k=-5$ in the second. Both are equally acceptable from a mathematical standpoint. However, because of human biases, we often prefer the $+C$, or, in your case, $+k$ formulation just to cut down on the number of minus signs. We're a pretty positive species, on the whole. 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, with the understanding that $k$ is an arbitrary constant.